# Change var in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop

```
var names = ['apple', 'pear', 'something']
var age = ['12','344','132']
```

(i have 20 vars like this)

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    Something(names[i]);
}
```

i get the type of something with an jquery `var name = $('[name=id]').val();`

is it possible to do an if else so if the `var name` is equal to any of the variables like here above then the names.length will change into that.

Example if the outcome of the `var name = $('[name=id]').val();` is age then the loop will change into

```
for (var i = 0; i < age.length; i++) {
    Something(age[i]);
}
```

Comment: Whenever you find yourself wanting to do dynamic variables, you really should be using an object to map the names to values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you store those variables into an object.

```
var container = {};
container.names = ['apple', 'pear', 'something'];
container.age = ['12','344','132'];

var name = $('[name=id]').val();

for (var i = 0; i < container[name].length; i++) {
    Something(container[name][i]);
}
```

**[edit]**
You can also check that what's stored in `name` corresponds to a valid array inside your container by calling `Array.isArray(container[name])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a quite different way.

Define all you variables in an object like below.

```
var data = {
    names: ['apple', 'pear', 'something'],
    age: ['12','344','132'],
    //...
}
```

here you get the type

```
var name = $('[name=id]').val();
```

Now do the loop like below, which should be as expected,

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[name].length; i++) {
    Something(data[name][i]);
}
```

Comment: I see @ValLeNain has answered while i was drafting. Thats a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying might be possible depending on the scope of your variables. For example, if they are set globally on `window`, then you could potentially use `Something(window[name][i]);`, however I wouldn't recommend doing this. Instead I would set up your code with an object instead of variables, like this:

```
var data = {
  names: ['apple', 'pear', 'something'],
  age: ['12', '344', '132']
};
```

Then you can simply do what you describe:

```
var name = $('[name=id]').val();
for (var i = 0; i < data[name].length; i++) {
  Something(data[name][i]);
}
```

Another way you could do this is by creating a function and passing in the appropriate variable:

```
var names = ['apple', 'pear', 'something']
var age = ['12','344','132']

function processItems(items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    Something(items[i]);
  }
}

switch ($('[name=id]').val()) {
  case 'name':
    processItems(name);
    break;
  case 'age':
    processItems(age);
    break;
}
```